# Ajax request into Bootstrap modal with a load spinner from Symfony controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I have created a modal to display information about a specific record when I click on the button.

```
{% for seat in seats %}
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg seat" id="{{ seat.id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#seatModal">
        <i style="color: lightgrey;" class="fa fa-stop fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <strong style="color: white;" class="fa-stack-1x">
            {{ seat.seatNo }}
        </strong>
    </span>
{% endfor %}

<div class="modal fade seat-details" id="seatModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have an Ajax request that get the information for the specific seat when clicking on that seat icon.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.seat').click(function() {
        var url = Routing.generate('show_seat', {'seat': $(this).attr('id')});
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $(".modal-content").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

This ajax call perform a request to the 'show_seat' route which lead to this controller action:

```
public function showSeatAction(Seat $seat)
{
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Seat:seat_details.html.twig', [
        'seat' => $seat,
    ]);
}
```

This action renders the details in the seat_details.html.twig;

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Seat Details</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body table-responsive no-padding">
    <table class="table table-modal">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <td>{{ seat.desc }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Seat Number</th>
                <td>{{ seat.seatNo }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <td>
                    {% if seat.status == 'special' %}
                        <span class="label label-info">{{ seat.status|upper }}</span>
                    {% elseif seat.status == 'bad' %}
                        <span class="label label-warning">{{ seat.status|upper }}</span>
                    {% else %}
                        <span class="label label-default">{{ seat.status|upper }}</span>
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And finally when the Ajax request is done it loads it into the modal as you can see in that Ajax function: `$(".modal-content").html(data);`.

This works good, but now I'm trying to add a spinner, because what happens now is when I click one the modal opens and the right data displays, but when I close it and open a new one the model opens with the previous data and then when the Ajax is done the text data get replaced in the modal.

But I want to let a spinner show until the Ajax is done and then the complete modal should display.

I've tried to add this:

```
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { $('.loading').show() },
    ajaxStop: function() { $('.loading').hide() }
});
```

This makes the spinner appear when clicking and hides it when Ajax is done, but the modal still appear too early. So I've tried to modify it to this:

```
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() {
        $('.loading').show();
        $('.seat-details').hide();
    },
    ajaxStop: function() {
        $('.loading').hide();
        $('.seat-details').show();
    }
});
```

But this doesn't change anything.

Can somebody help me out to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var seatModal =  $("#seatModal");//your modal 

$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() {
        seatModal.find(".modal-content").html("");//empty modal every ajaxstart
        $('.loading').show();
        seatModal.modal("hide");//hide

    },
    ajaxStop: function() {
        $('.loading').hide();
        seatModal.modal("show");//modal show
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process with an other way. Initialize your modal with nothing in it.

Then, when the user close the modal, remove the content and replace it with your spinner.

```
$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
    $(".modal-content").html([your spinner here]);
});
```